# Problem with php mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

am getting these errors while running php mailer. What could be the problem

```
MAMP/htdocs/practice/email/email.php on line 2
[06-Jun-2011 09:53:40] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: from in     /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/practice/phpmailer/phpmailer.inc.php on line 259
[06-Jun-2011 09:53:40] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: Encoding in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/practice/phpmailer/phpmailer.inc.php on line 271
[06-Jun-2011 09:53:40] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/practice/phpmailer/phpmailer.inc.php on line 271
```

Comment: What is on the line with the Fatal error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be sure that you are using [the latest release of PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), 5.1.  There is no such file "phpmailer.inc.php" in that release, which implies that the code you're using is either entirely incorrect or horribly obsolete.  Indeed, the only reference I could find to that file is from a release dating back to 2003.

You might also want to consider using a more modern mailing library instead, like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Answer (score 2):

The download link on PHPMailer's website is wrong. Instead of downloading PHPMailer v. 5+ you downloaded PHPMailer 4. Edit the download link and change the # 4 to 5. Then you get the correct version.